# C++ output * table

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a table in C++ that asks you for the length of the sides and outputs a star table.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I should be doing to get the table to start displaying correctly?

input:

```
Enter length of side: 5
```

wanted output:

```
*****
*   *
*   *
*   *
*   *
*****
```

what I have so far outputs the first line of *'s minus one then displays the number you input.

```
#include "main.h"
using namespace std;


    int main () {
      int sideLength;
      cout << "Enter lengh of side: ";
      cin >> sideLength;
      cout.fill('*');
      cout.width(sideLength);
      cout << sideLength << endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

thanks in advanced, just learning c++

Comment: I don't think you understand what `width()` does: it just sets the minimal width of the next output. To get it to this width, the output is padded by the fill character.

Comment: Dietmar - oh! so it's not like Java where you just set the width(here)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  int sideLength;
  cout << "Enter lengh of side: ";
  cin >> sideLength;

  for (int i = 0; i < sideLength; i++)
    cout<<"*";

  cout<<"\n";

  for (int i = 0; i < sideLength-2; i++) 
  {
    cout<<"*";

    for (int j = 0; j < sideLength-2; j++)
      cout<<" ";

    cout<<"*"<<"\n";
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < sideLength; i++)
    cout<<"*";

  cout<<"\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this makes the most sense to me. I guess what I was thinking is that there was a cout.height that I didn't know about that I could use.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite get this cute, yet. Maybe I can come up with something nicer...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    int size;
    if (std::cin >> size) {
        auto to(std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout));
        auto line([=](decltype(to) to){ return std::fill_n(to, size, '*'); });
        auto box([=](decltype(to) to){
                *to++ = '*'; std::fill_n(to, size - 2, ' '); *to++ = '*'; return to;
            });
        *(to = line(to))++ = '\n';
        for (int i(1); ++i < size; ) {
            *(to = box(to))++ = '\n';
        }
        *(to = line(to))++ = '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Let's try to keep in mind that the OP is "just learning c++" :)

Comment: Yea, that's a bit too complex for me to understand since I've never seen "auto" and such before. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

You should add a loop to print the sides and the bottom, too.
Suggestion:

```
for (int i=0; i <= sideLength; i++)  
{
cout<<endl <<"*";
for (int j=0; j < sideLength;j++) 
{
cout<<" ";
cout<<"*";
}
cout.fill('*');
```

Add these line after line cout.fill('*').
Maybe it will work.

Comment: almost, it creates a full table. but doesn't leave blank space in the middle.